# Unable to access SVG DOM after reload with Electron

Tags: javascript, html, svg, electron

I am putting an interactive SVG element on a page in an Electron app and as such I need to access elements inside of an external SVG document with Javascript. Everything works as intended until I reload the page. After reloading I cannot access the external SVG DOM from an inline or external script, nor from the console. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

To test things out I created an unpackaged Electron app (version 5.0.4 as well as 5.0.6) from scratch based on the getting started with Electron page. I then put in three identical, simple SVGs, one with the 'object' tag, one with the 'embed' tag, and one inline. I wrote some code to send the first element to the console once each SVG has loaded. Upon initially starting the app all three elements appear on the page and in the console as expected.

I then reload the app with Ctrl+R (or Ctrl+Shift+R) and while all three elements still appear on the page only the element from the inline SVG appears in the console. The other two give errors about reading a property of null. Using contentDocument or getSVGDocument() through the console on the 'object' or 'embed' tags respectively return null whereas they did not before a reload. The same is true when using Jquery instead of the getElementById method. I can't even find the external document through the elements explorer in the Chromium developer console.

Here is the code I just described:

```html
<object id="object" data="bookmark.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>

<embed id="embed" src="bookmark.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></embed>

<svg id="inline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="enable-background:new 0 0 24 24;" xml:space="preserve" width="96px" height="96px">
  <g id="Sharp_3_">
    <path d="M16,2v10l-3-2l-3,2V2H6C4.895,2,4,2.895,4,4v15c1,0,0.895-2,2-2h14V2H16z"/>
    <path style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M20,17H7c-1.105,0-2,0.895-2,2s0.895,2,2,2h13"/>
  </g>
</svg>

<script>
  document.getElementById("object").onload = function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("object").contentDocument.children[0].children[0]);
  }

  document.getElementById("embed").onload = function() { 
    console.log(document.getElementById("embed").getSVGDocument().children[0].children[0]);
  }

  console.log(document.getElementById("inline").children[0]);
</script>
```

The console returns the following before a reload:

```
index.html:23  <g id="Sharp_3_">...</g>

index.html:26  <g id="Sharp_3_">...</g>

index.html:28  <g id="Sharp_3_">...</g>
```

And after a reload:

```
index.html:28  <g id="Sharp_3_">...</g>

index.html:23  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null at HTMLObjectElement.document.getElementById.onload (index.html:23)

index.html:26  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null at HTMLObjectElement.document.getElementById.onload (index.html:26)
```

I would expect this to produce the same result after a reload--even if it was always working or not--and that is what makes me think this is a bug. However, I am new to Electron and could very well be missing something about security or application structure that I have not come across yet. I have done some looking and have yet to find something specifically about this issue. I did find some stuff about reloading causing a blank page or caching causing issues with SVGs but I don't know how I can apply it to this issue.

I could just never reload and find a way to keep users from reloading but that would slow down my iteration speed considerably. I could write the script in the SVGs but I have multiple SVGs that need to respond to the same code at the same time. Any other workarounds or solutions would be appreciated but this may just be a bug, I can't be sure.